# Raw types and performance

Tags: java, generics

On page 140 of Effective Java we are advised that a method signature with a wildcard is preferable to one with a type parameter that only appears once. For example,

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j)
```

is preferable to

```
public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int i, int j)
```

However it is not possible to set an item of a `List<?>` to be anything (except `null`) so Effective Java suggests writing a private helper method to make the signature with a wildcard work.

```
private static <T> void swapHelper(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
    list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));
}

public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    swapHelper(list, i, j);
}
```

However I looked at the source code for `Collections.swap` and discovered that the way that they got around the `List<?>` problem was to use *raw types*.

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

We are advised not to use raw types in new code (except in `instanceof` checks). So, I would like to know what is the reason here? Is there a performance benefit in using raw types here rather than calling a private helper method? If not, are there any examples where using raw types can improve performance?

Comment: Raw types could be avoided, by using `List<Object>` instead of `List`, but that would be an unchecked cast, which in this case is no less unsafe than the raw type.

Comment: *"(except in instanceof checks)"* This is not true. `instanceof List<?>` is fine and preferred. ; )

Comment: @Radiodef Not according to Effective Java (2nd edition) page 114.

Comment: It's fine to do but I'd argue it's an error to recommend it, even for a book so reputable. It could also be the book is outdated since (according to the JLS) raw types predated wildcards and therefore there was a time when one did not have wildcards to use in an `instanceof` expression. And of course it is possible raw types may be disallowed in future versions of Java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8

Comment: @Radiodef The full quote is `// Legitimate use of raw type - instanceof operator if (o instanceof Set)  { Set<?> m = (Set<?>) o; ...}` I for one hope that they do disallow raw types in a future version of Java. What we need is a shiny new backwards incompatible version of Java that corrects a lot of the mistakes and sorts out some of the mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. You will most likely find it to be the case that the JIT compiler inlines both your swap method and your swapHelper method if they turn out to be performance bottlenecks. In general, the Java JIT compiler is very good in detecting performance bottlenecks.

However, if you're interested about performance then why not write a benchmark for both the Collections.swap method and your variant which uses a helper method. That would provide you with an answer to this question. Just be sure to do enough many iterations that the JIT compiler recognises the swap functions as bottlenecks and optimizes the bottlenecks away by inlining the method calls.

I would follow the advice given by Effective Java instead of the code in Collections.swap. I think you just found evidence that programmers take shortcuts sometimes. It doesn't mean you should be doing the same.

Comment: Normally when people say premature optimization is the root of all evil, they are advocating that people write simple, clear code rather than convoluted code that they think might run faster. You're almost arguing the opposite. You're saying that the convoluted version with two methods is preferable here because it's more important to avoid raw types than it is to write simple code. What's the evil here?

Comment: The evil is using a version of the code which accesses the list as a raw type with no generics information. Yes, in my opinion it is better to avoid raw types than to write code that has low line count. Although low line count is important, many low-line-count solutions are quite hackish. Just see e.g. answers in the programming puzzles & code golf site. You don't definitely want those low-line-count solutions in your production code!

Comment: I've accepted your answer as you've convinced me that performance wasn't the reason, and I agree it probably was just the author taking a shortcut (especially as the `Collections` class was already written before generics). However I'm beginning to think that there are exceptions to the "never use raw types" rule. For example, I can't see that the diamond operator in `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` adds anything at all (apart from making the author feel good about not using raw types). I think avoiding the `swapHelper` method is a much better example though.

Comment: Java Standard Edition is absolutely littered with trivial micro-optimization. This is almost certainly micro-optimization. But also I agree finding stuff like this in SE is not evidence that we should do it ourselves.